# Is GCP Cloud Functions the right tool for processing large .csv files?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-functions

My goal is to allow users to import relatively large sets of data into MongoDB (hosted on mongo cloud). Api server is hosted in the container engine and it doesn't have any other operations with such a big load (only simple CRUD operations).

Users will be uploading .csv files (up to 100mb) to GCP Bucket, from there i need to validate and upsert each row from the csv file into MongoDB and then do some calculations based on the imported data.
Is that the right fit for GCP Cloud Functions? I'm a bit concerned about 540 seconds execution duration limit.

Comment: I would recommend using Cloud Dataflow to manage the import into Mongo.  From there, you might run another Dataflow pipeline to run your calculations or simply do that in your app.

Answer (score 1):

This rather seems like a good use case for Apache Beam / Dataflow. With Beam 2.2 you can write a streaming pipeline that will continuously ingest new files in the bucket, using `TextIO.read().from(...).watchForNewFiles(...)` - see [javadoc](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextIO.java#L110).